# What does "it lucky" mean?

Tags: meaning

> Walking into his office with my news was not exactly easy, but I
> thought it lucky to be delivering it to him.

I search the meaning of [lucky](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/lucky) but I still don't understand the meaning of the sentence. Does it mean:

> I thought it *likely* to be delivering it to him.

Could you please explain it to me?

The fuller text:

> Only then did I realize how few influential people I knew well enough
> to ask for help. First of all, I decided, I would call Rudolf’s boss,
> Minister of Foreign Trade Antonin Gregor. After all, Rudolf was his
> immediate subordinate, his deputy minister. He could not have done
> anything without Gregor’s authorization. Gregor was routinely informed
> of every move Rudolf made – he had to stand by him. And the other
> deputy minister, Jonas, had always treated us like close friends, if
> not relations. He would hug me whenever we met. I would call both of
> them as soon as their offices opened. I threw off Rudolf’s robe,
> dressed, and forced a cup of Marenka’s black coffee down my throat.
> Before I left, I went into the nursery to check on Ivan. He was fast
> asleep, smiling, his cheeks flushed. Nothing had touched him yet. At
> that time my editor-in-chief was Jura Zajonc, a bright, good-natured
> young man who came from a long line of miners. He was, of course, a
> dedicated Communist, but I had always suspected he had a mind of his
> own. **Walking into his office with my news was not exactly easy, but
> I thought it lucky to be delivering it to him**.

From *Under A Cruel Star* by  Heda Margolius Kovály

Translated from the Czech
by Helen Epstein with the author

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means "lucky" (normal dictionary meaning).  I would paraphrase as

> I thought I was lucky to be the person delivering the news to Mr Zajonc

With the shift from "I think I am lucky [to do this])" to "I think [doing this] is lucky (for me)"

Here is another example

> I thought it lucky for me that it was Mr Aldous who was tasked with finding the speaker for this year’s dinner, for if it had been someone who actually knew me while I was [at school] I may very well never have received the call.

Meaning "I was lucky that it was Mr Aldous who...

Comment: Or perhaps "I thought it was lucky that _he_ was the person receiving my news".

Comment: I feel I'd need to read the entire book to be confident in this, but an alternative might be "I thought myself lucky", i.e. "I felt I was in a slightly advantageous position".

Answer (score 2):

There's an idiomatic expression "<to> think it <adjective>..." that means "think [that it is/was] <adjective>...".

For example, if I say "He thinks it inappropriate she left so early" I simply mean "He thinks that it was inappropriate that she left so early".

This construction can also be used with other thought-related verbs: substitute "believe", "regard", "consider", etc. with "think".

Here's [an example](https://digitalcommons.law.ou.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=5334&context=indianserialset): [image]

In this case, it could be paraphrased as "Your committee [note the British English convention on plurality here] do not regard it as strange that..."